# Laravel Validation Arrays - Sometimes Ignore field if another field exists in an array

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I'm writing some validation rules for a Laravel application and I need to ignore some fields if another field is present. I know that the "sometimes" functionality is probably the best way to go, but how to implement the functionality with an array?

**First attempt** (didn't work, because Laravel validates any time the field is present):

```
// Device Rules
$deviceRules = [
    'devices' => 'required|array|min:1',
    'devices.*.id' => 'integer',
    'devices.*.network' => 'max:255',

    'devices.*.code' => "required_without:devices.*.id|max:255|unique:devices,code",
    'devices.*.make_id' => 'required_without:devices.*.id|in:' . Make::getImplodedKeys(),
    'devices.*.model_id' => 'required_without:devices.*.id|in:' . DeviceModel::getImplodedKeys(),

    'devices.*.fault_id' => 'required|array|min:1',
    'devices.*.fault_id.*' => 'in:' . Fault::getImplodedKeys(),
    'devices.*.warranty' => 'required|boolean'
]
```

**So my second attempt using 'sometimes()'** (but I don't quite know how to implement this.):

```
public function rules()
{
    // Device Rules
    $deviceRules = [
        'devices' => 'required|array|min:1',
        'devices.*.id' => 'integer',
        'devices.*.network' => 'max:255',

        'devices.*.fault_id' => 'required|array|min:1',
        'devices.*.fault_id.*' => 'in:' . Fault::getImplodedKeys(),
        'devices.*.warranty' => 'required|boolean'
    ];

    return $deviceRules ;
}

protected function getValidatorInstance(){
    $validator = parent::getValidatorInstance();

    $validator->sometimes('devices.*.code', 'required|max:255|unique:devices,code', function($input)
    {
        return isset($input->devices.*.id);
    });

    $validator->sometimes('devices.*.make_id', 'required|in:' . Make::getImplodedKeys(), function($input)
    {
        return isset($input->devices.*.id);
    });

    $validator->sometimes('devices.*.model_id', 'required|in:' . DeviceModel::getImplodedKeys(), function($input)
    {
        return isset($input->devices.*.id);
    });

    return $validator;
}
```

I haven't tested this because obviously it won't work, `return isset($input->devices.*.id);` will without doubt throw an error. How can I properly implement this?

Comment: can you please specify the vaidation logic for when the sometimes field is required?

Comment: @pseudoanime Thanks for your comment. I've found a solution now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I found my own solution**

See below:

```
// Device Rules
$deviceRules = [
    'devices' => 'required|array|min:1',
    'devices.*.id' => 'integer',
    'devices.*.network' => 'max:255'
];

foreach($this['devices'] as $index => $device){
    if(!isset($device['id'])){

        $additionalDeviceRules = [
            'devices.' .$index. '.code' => 'required|max:255|unique:devices,code',
            'devices.' .$index. '.make_id' => 'required|in:' . Make::getImplodedKeys(),
            'devices.' .$index. '.model_id' => 'required|in:' . DeviceModel::getImplodedKeys(),

            'devices.' .$index. '.fault_id' => 'required|array|min:1',
            'devices.' .$index. '.fault_id.*' => 'in:' . Fault::getImplodedKeys(),
            'devices.' .$index. '.warranty' => 'required|boolean'
        ];

        $deviceRules = array_merge($deviceRules, $additionalDeviceRules);
    }
}
```

Basically, instead of using the placeholder index `*` you need to specify the index id. Laravel can then parse the index id and apply your rules conditionally.